# Peticion Ajax utilizando post

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

Tengo este formulario

```
<form id="form2">
<h2 style="text-align: center;"> Te avisamos cuando este disponible </h2>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreF" name="nombreF" placeholder="Nombre" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailF" name="emailF" placeholder="Email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Mensaje</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="mensajeF" name="mensajeF" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button id="sendf" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Mi duda es como enviar los datos que tengo en cada `input` y como recogerlos. He intentado lo siguiente pero no me funciona.

```
document.getElementById("sendf").addEventListener("click", correo);
function correo(){
var nombreF = document.getElementById("nombreF").value;
var emailF = document.getElementById("emailF").value;
var mensajeF = document.getElementById("mensajeF").value;
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"correo.php",
  data: {nombreF:nombreF,emailF:emailF,mensajeF:mensajeF},
  success:function(datos){
    if(datos){
      document.getElementById("formu").innerHTML = "Mensaje enviado";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("formu").innerHTML = "Mensaje fallado";
    }
  }
 })
}
```

Me gustaría como utilizar lo que le paso a mi `correo.php` yo lo he intentado con `$nombre = $_POST[nombreF]` pero no lo recoge y otra duda es si en `success` es el `return` de mi `php` que quiero que si devuelvo **true** haga una cosa y si es **false** otra.
 Esta es mi respuesta del php

```
$estadoEnvio = $mail->Send();
 if($estadoEnvio){
   $respuesta ="1";
 } else {
   $respuesta="2";
 }
 echo $respuesta;
```

Comment: Estas enviando `nombreF` pero estas chequeando por `nombre`

Comment: perdon tengo nombreF

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? ¿Depuraste los datos que estás enviando? ¿Los envías al archivo PHP correcto? ¿Los recoges de forma correcta en el PHP (debería ser así: `$_POST["nombreF"]`, usando comillas) ¿Qué devuelves desde ese PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno empezando podrías intentar recoger todos los datos del `form` con un `serialize()` y para lo segundo `ajax` solamente recoge una respuesta en texto plano, por lo tanto sí quieres devolver algo en `ajax` desde `php` debes hacer imprimiendo algo en el archivo `php`, en este caso quieres hacer un **true** o un **false**, entonces hazlos equivalentes a **"1"** y **"0"** para que sea más simple, entonces los imprimes con un `echo` en el archivo `php` y quedaría algo así:

```
document.getElementById("sendf").addEventListener("click", correo);
function correo(){
var datos = $("#form2").serialize();
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"correo.php",
  data: datos,
  success:function(response){
    console.log(response); // revisa lo que te devuelve en consola
    if(response.trim() == "1"){ // El trim() es para que quite los espacios al final y al principo de la cadena, aveces pasa es para prevenir.
      document.getElementById("formu").innerHTML = "Mensaje enviado";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("formu").innerHTML = "Mensaje fallado";
    }
  }
 })
}
```

Ojalá te sirva, saludos!

Comment: y en el php como recogo los datos del serialize?

Comment: Normal, como un `post` normal, él toma los `name=` de cada uno de los elementos, entonces sería `$nombre = $_POST["nombreF"];`

Comment: perdona que te moleste puse echo "1" , pero eso me lo pone en el correo.php no vuelve a la página del form

Comment: podrías agregar un momento el archivo `php` a la pregunta, lo que sucede con ajax, es que el hace la petición y devuelve todo lo que imprima el archivo, entonce sí haces un `console.log(response)` en consola debería mostrarte lo que imprime `correo.php`

Comment: Ya puse lo que tengo, lo que pasa esque el echo lo hace en mi correo.php, y no regresa a donde hice la petición

Comment: Mira lo del `console.log` que agregué a la pregunta y pruebalo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar de la siguiente manera con JSON.stringify() y serializeArray():

```
document.getElementById("sendf").addEventListener("click", correo);
function correo(){

var data = JSON.stringify($('#form2').serializeArray());

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "correo.php",
  data: data,
  success: function(datos){
    if(datos){
      document.getElementById("formu").innerHTML = "Mensaje enviado";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("formu").innerHTML = "Mensaje fallado";
    }
  }
 })
}
```